# how to redirect to previous page after loggin

Tags: c#, asp.net

In loggin comtrol I have ridrect the user to same url after login.In comment control when unregistered or unlogin user tries to comment I show him message which redirects hin in login control.Now I need to redirect him again back to comment page after login but I am in big dillema.

The following are my codes:

login.ascx.cs

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            txtPassword.Text = obj.Encrypt(txtPassword.Text.Trim(), true);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select id,username,password From registration where username=@UserName And password= @password ", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtusername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
            //MySqlDataAdapter da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter("select id,username from registration where username='" + txtusername.Text + "'", con);
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            con.Close();

            string message = null;


            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                String t1 = dt.Rows[0]["id"].ToString();
                String username = dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString();

                Session["UserId"] = t1;
                Session["username"] = username;

                Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
                Console.WriteLine(MyUrl);
                if (MyUrl != null)
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

                string userName = Session["username"].ToString();
                //pnllogin.Visible = false;
                 message = "Hello " + userName + ", Welcome to our website.";
                 //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup1('" + message + "');", true);
            }



            else
            {
                 message = "Sorry You cannot login, please provide correct Email and password";

            }
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);





        }
```

comment.ascx.cs

protected void btncomment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
    {
        if (Session["userid"] != null)
        {
            main AddComment = new main();
            string mandir_id = Request.QueryString["id"];

```
        sQLcONN.Open();
        string SQL2 = "insert into comment (user_id,Comment,with_temple) values ('" + Session["userid"] + "','" + txtComment.Text + "','" + mandir_id + "')";
        sQLcONN.Close();
        AddComment.saveData(SQL2);
        Bindcomment();



    }
    else
    {
        //ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
       // Response.Write("You Must Login Or Register To Comment");
       // lblcommentmsg.Text="You Must Login Or Register To Comment";

        string message = "You Must Login Or Register To Comment";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you store the URL in Session before you redirect them to login?

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying.Please explain me clearly thankyou.

Comment: `In comment control when unregistered or unlogin user tries to comment I show him message which redirects hin in login control.` If I understand this correctly, you let users access comments, but when trying to post, you redirect them to login, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before actual redirection of unauthenticated users to the login page, why not introduce something like `Session["returnPath"] = Request.RawUrl;` and then when users get authenticated:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Session["returnPath"]))
    Response.Redirect(Session["returnPath"]);
```

Additionally, ASP.NET MVC uses a `returnUrl` URL parameter instead of a session valuable. So your login URL would look like: `http://www.example.com/Login?returnUrl=/the-page-you-were-on.aspx`. Seems to work well.

Comment: Yes I did same like this and its work.Thankyou so much.

Comment: @Dan-o Thanks for the edit Dan, but he seems to be creating his own kind of Membership. @ user3247426 No worries.

Comment: @nphx: I realize that, I was just providing an alternative to your session option (a url parameter).  And your post explained how to implement the redirect, so I just edited your post.  Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Dan-o Ah, now I understand that you were trying to suggest the reimplementation of the query string option instead of using it as if it were already there ;)